# what exactly makes these two getdate() different

Tags: sql

```
    dateadd(D, 1, getdate()), dateadd(Y, 1, getdate())
```

What is the difference between these two? Can anyone explain why they are giving same result?

I am trying to get training completed date should be greater than or equal to one year. Also, I need to find who is going to come and join in next 30 days, based on training completed date.

Comment: . . Why is this tagged "mysql".  `getdate()` is not a recognized function in MySQL.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or T-SQL? Seems as though you are confused.

Comment: The first argument of `date_add` (not `dateadd`) is *units*, it should be one of the names from [this list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add). Are you sure it's MySQL syntax?

Answer (score 1):

For the second one "y" gets the day of year, it is not saying add a year. So they both are saying the same thing. First one says add one day to the current day and the second one says add one day to the current day of this year. To add a year you need to say dateadd(YY, 1, getdate()).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

I don't follow your last statement about what you are trying to do. But if you use the datepart defined in the above link you should be able to add the number of days/months/years you need.

Comment: can you help me in this emp should complete training every and i need to show list no of emp coming to join in next 30 days of next year

Comment: Still not sure I follow what you are trying to do Ram. You need to get a list of employees joining in the next 30 days based on what? I assume you have a datetime field in your database that is their start date? So you need to get a list of all employees who's start date is within the next 30 days? Than once you have that you need to know if they have completed training?

Answer (score 1):

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97730/5) demonstrates the difference between the two.

For example, using the current date (`GETDATE()`) as the date in the database, we have a table that might look something like...

```
id    date
1     March, 25 2013 18:20:29+0000
...
```

The first parameter is the `datepart`. This can be a `year (yy,yyyy)`, `quarter (qq,q)`, `dayofyear (dy,y)`, etc... The whole list may be found at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

We use D for day... This will add 1 day to the date.
`SELECT dateadd(D,1,getdate()) FROM test;` will return `March, 26 2013 18:24:27+0000`.

While you might think Y would be used for year, you'd be incorrect. Y is used for the *day of year*. We must use `YY` or `YYYY` for a year to be added.

`SELECT dateadd(Y,1,getdate()) FROM test;` will result in `March, 26 2013 18:24:27+0000`, which is the same as our previous query. This is because the day of the year is the same as the day.

`SELECT dateadd(YY,1,getdate()) FROM test;` will output the expected `getdate()` + `1 year`... (`March, 25 2014 18:31:27+0000`)